# Quick Test Pro (Regression test scripts) - Cruisecontrol.net

Tags: cruisecontrol, qtp

Any one succeeded in integrating Quick Test Pro (QTP) automated test scripts in Cruisecontrol.net.

if any one have an idea to run them unattended , in a schedule task or cruisecontrol.net

will be more useful.#

Answer (score 2):

I am sure this will be possible using the QTP Automation Object Model. See 'QuickTest Automation' in the 'QuickTest Advanced References' section of the on-line help. You should be able to create a simple batch file to run QTP which can then be invoked via NAnt and/or CruiseControl.